# I want to search and replace in a text file using perl but the regex expression s/// is not working as expected

Tags: perl

I wish to replace

```
R00001,abcd xyz pqr,undef,undef,PEND
```

with

```
R00001,abcd xyz pqr,undef,undef,DONE
```

I tried using

```
 $line =~ s/(\w+,\w+,\w+,\w+),\w+/$1,"DONE"/g;
```

The issue is that abcd xyz pqr has spaces in it and so it's not able to sync with \w+. What changes can I make to this part of the code so that it works?

Thanks

Comment: `$line=~s/\,([^\,]*)$/\,DONE/g;`

Answer (score 2):

why not simply 

`$line =~ s/PEND/DONE/;`

if you want to keep a regex similar to the one you used, you can 
`$line =~ s/(\w+,[\w\s]+,\w+,\w+),\w+/$1,"DONE"/g;`

Answer (score 2):

Pulling a wheel off the shelf:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Text::CSV::Easy qw( csv_parse );

while (<DATA>) {
    my @row = csv_parse $_;
    $row[ 4 ] = 'DONE' if $row[ 4 ] eq 'PEND';
    say join',', @row;
}

__DATA__
R00001,abcd xyz pqr,undef,undef,PEND
```

OUTPUT:

```
R00001,abcd xyz pqr,undef,undef,DONE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow for whitespace in any of your fields, you can do this:

```
$line =~ s/^((?:[\w\s]+,){4})[\w\s]+$/$1DONE/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

My question is why should we should bother about the spaces. You have a operator `,` at the before keyword hence Its might be simple replacement.

`$line=~s/\,([^\,]*)$/\,DONE/g;`

Regex explanation:

```
$line=~s/\, #Check the last comma
           ([^\,]*)  #Rest of the words (PEND)
                     $ # End of the line 
              /\,DONE/g; #Replace whatever you want (DONE)
```

Comment: Needs [`/x`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Details-on-some-modifiers), right?

Comment: Yes. However just brief info for understanding on the regex.